# Angular2 - after SebmGoogleMapMarker event "markerClick" triggers, view is not updating

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I have an array which looks like this:

```
    locations: marker[] = [
    {id: '1',  lat: 51.5239935252832,    lng:  5.137663903579778,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker.png'},
    {id: '2',  lat: 51.523853342911906,  lng:  5.1377765563584035,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '3',  lat: 51.5237298485607,    lng:  5.137969675407476,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '4',  lat: 51.52355628836575,   lng:  5.138066234932012,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '5',  lat: 51.52340275379578,   lng:  5.138211074218816,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '6',  lat: 51.523199152806626,  lng:  5.138382735595769,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png' },
    {id: '7',  lat: 51.5229955509073,    lng:  5.138511481628484,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '8',  lat: 51.52280529912936,   lng:  5.138543668136663,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '9',  lat: 51.523596340777075,  lng:  5.138463201866216,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '700',lat: 51.523372714362736,  lng:  5.1386992362595265,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'},
    {id: '101', lat: 51.52329594683302,  lng:  5.138838711128301,   content: 'Kids Jungalow Giraffe', iconUrl: 'img/marker2.png'}
];
```

If I click on a marker it opens a section with the information of the selected marker.

Here the html of the googlemaps:

```
<sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let location of locations" (markerClick)="updateDiv(location)"></sebm-google-map-marker>
```

Here the function updateDiv():

```
updateDiv(location: Location) {
    this.selectedLocation = location;
}
```

Here is the markup of the div where I want to display the id of `locations`

```
<div *ngIf="selectedLocation" class="result-number">{{ selectedLocation.id }}</div>
```

But it seems not to work!

Comment: Did you check `updatDiv()` gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to explicitly call the `detectChanges` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef` class:

```
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

(...)

updateDiv(location: Location) {
  this.selectedLocation = location;
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

First check that the method is actually called with the right `location` and the `selectedLocation` is updated within the TypeScript class.

If this doesn't work, you can leverage `NgZone`:

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {
}

(...)

updateDiv(location: Location) {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.selectedLocation = location;
  });
}
```

Processing could be triggered initially from an object (a Google Maps one) that is created outside the scope of an Angular2 component...